# Searching/duplicating multiple files in folder using Applescript

Tags: applescript, finder

I have a text file of around 500 selected file names (each on its own line) from an event I photographed with over 3,000 pictures.  I want to be able to find all those images in the folder, duplicate them, and move those duplicated files into a different folder.

This is what I have so far.  Right now it just copies the entire folder of 3,000 images and puts it into the destination folder, but not the individual files..

TEXT FILE:

```
_EPW0847.jpg
_EPW0848.jpg
_EPW0853.jpg
etc....
```

APPLESCRIPT:

```
set thePhotos to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Choose a text file"))
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder") as string
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
repeat with theName in thePhotos
    try
        tell application "Finder" to duplicate alias (theSourceFolder & theName) to theDestination with replacing
    end try
end repeat
tell application "Finder"
    tell folder theDestination to set theCount1 to (count of items) as string
end tell
set theCount2 to (count of thePhotos) as string
display dialog (theCount1 & " of " & theCount2 & " items copied to " & theDestination) buttons {"OK"}
```

Any help would be great. I don't know apple script that well yet, but I'm learning. Thanks!

Comment: Weird but your code works for me as is (Sierra).

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

```
set thePhotos to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Choose a text file"))
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder")
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
set dupeList to {}
repeat with theName in thePhotos
    try
        set end of dupeList to alias ((theSourceFolder as text) & theName)
    end try
end repeat

tell application "Finder" to duplicate dupeList to theDestination with replacing

set theCount1 to (count of dupeList) as text
set theCount2 to (count of thePhotos) as text
display dialog (theCount1 & " of " & theCount2 & " items copied to " & (theDestination as text)) buttons {"OK"}
```

If there are blank lines in the text file, try this:

```
set thePhotos to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Choose a text file"))
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder")
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
set dupeList to {}

repeat with theName in thePhotos
    try
        if theName ≠ "" then
            set end of dupeList to alias ((theSourceFolder as text) & theName)
        end if
    end try
end repeat
```

Comment: hmmm.. it's still copying the entire folder.  Is it the format of the TXT file? Should it be in CSV format?

Comment: that didn't work either, but I found an option and it works for me.  I had to change to a CSV file, but I don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set fileContents to read (choose file with prompt "Choose a comma-delimited text file")
set theText to result
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set theTextItems to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
theTextItems
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder") as string
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
repeat with theEPSName in theTextItems
   tell application "Finder"
       set theEPSFile to theSourceFolder & theEPSName
       move file theEPSFile to folder theDestination with replacing
   end tell
end repeat
```